# Cheapest path in a bipartide weighted graph DFS/Greedy BFS

Tags: python, graph, path, depth-first-search

I have a bipartide weighted graph (more exactly an assignment problem) and I want to find the cheapest path/selection. Any idea how I would implement DFS or Greedy BFS to achieve the path?

I have the graph represented as an adiacency list (or so I think would be best) like this and the DFS algorithm

```
adjlist = {"A": ["W", "X"],
           "B": ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"],
           "C": ["Y", "Z"],
           "D": ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"],
           "W": ["A", "B", "D"],
           "X": ["A", "B", "D"],
           "Y": ["B", "C", "D"],
           "Z": ["B", "C", "D"] }

def dfser(graph, root):
    visited =[]
    stack = [root, ]

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node not in visited:
            visited.append(node)
            stack.extend([x for x in graph[node] if x not in visited])
    return visited
```

Is it possible what I want? The result must be something like: AWBXCYDZ or something with the cheapest sum.

Or can I get all the possible traversals from root? This DFS only gives me one but I want all the possible tranversals

Comment: Is this homework? If not you could look at the `networkx` module which has implemented many of these algorithms. You would also get more help if you show what you've tried and what you are specifically stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) are not designed to shortest path search, especially in a weighted graph.

Looking for the cheapest path could be performed with the [dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) or the [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithms.
Networkx provides a [full API](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html) for that task.

The networkx module implements [bipartite graphs](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html#module-networkx.algorithms.bipartite.basic) and related algorithms :

```
Dicti = {"A": {"W": 2, "X": 2},
     "B": {"W": 4, "X": 3, "Y": 2, "Z": 5},
     "C": {"Y": 2, "Z": 2},
     "D": {"W": 5, "X": 5, "Y": 4, "Z": 3},
     "W": {"A": 2, "B": 4, "D": 5},
     "X": {"A": 2, "B": 3, "D": 5},
     "Y": {"B": 2, "C": 2, "D": 4},
     "Z": {"B": 5, "C": 2, "D": 3}
}

graph = nx.Graph()
for node, succs in Dicti.items():
    for succ, weight in succs:
        graph.add_edge(node, succ, weight=weight)

print(nx.dijkstra_path(graph, 'A', 'Z'))  # here is Dijkstra
```

Comment: Yea but I wanted to know if it's possible to solve it with DFS or greedy BFS? Dijkstra and A* doesn't really help me

Comment: [Best-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) could solve the problem, but is a heuristic, so the result can potentially be not optimal.

Comment: Note that the A* algorithm is a particular case of the Best-First Search, where the *best* node is the nearer.

Comment: It is possible to solve with BFS/DFS but involves finding all paths and then minimizing, at which point the choice between BFS/DFS is largely irrelevant (same time/complexity). Dijkstra or A* are more efficient at finding the optimal solution.

Comment: Ok since I want DFS & GBFS basically I must traverse the graph and get 24 different results then compute their sums and sort them? How do I make DFS to give me more traversal variances?

Comment: I edited my post. Added a DFS version for my list but I want all the possible traversals. How would I do that?